# How to build tensorflow custom operations on windows

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

I've been trying to get a custom operation working with a Windows version of TensorFlow. I've followed the guide:

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/op#build_a_pip_package_for_your_custom_op

I was able to build correctly, but it seems my custom operation is not recognized still when I try to run a test on it.

It seems to recognize the built-in custom operation `tf.user_ops.my_fact`, 
but it does not recognize the `user_ops` I created: `squared_out`.

Here's what I did step by step:

1. Clone the repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
```

2. I put my C++ implementation of `squared_out.cc` in tensorflow\tensorflow\core\user_ops

```cpp
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/shape_inference.h"

using namespace tensorflow;

REGISTER_OP("SquaredOut")
    .Input("to_square: int32")
    .Output("squared: int32")
    .SetShapeFn([](::tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext *c) {
        c->set_output(0, c->input(0));
        return Status::OK();
    });


class SquaredOutOp : public OpKernel {

    public:
        explicit SquaredOutOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {}

        void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {

            const Tensor& input_tensor = context->input(0);
            auto input = input_tensor.flat<int32>();

            Tensor* output_tensor = NULL;
            OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(0, input_tensor.shape(), &output_tensor));

            auto output_flat = output_tensor->flat<int32>();

            const int N = input.size();

            for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i){

                output_flat(i) = input(i) * input(i);

            }
        }
};

REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("SquaredOut").Device(DEVICE_CPU), SquaredOutOp);
```

3. Afterwards I configure and built the tensorflow library by using bazel:

```
python ./configure.py
bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
bazel-bin\tensorflow\tools\pip_package\build_pip_package C:/tmp/tensorflow_pkg
```

4. I then installed the .whl that was produced by bazel:

```
pip install C:/tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-version-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

5. Finally, I tried to test the newly imported `squared_out` from `user_ops`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
#This works fine with build in fact function
tf.user_ops.fact
```

This returned:

```
<function my_fact at 0x0000020CE5601048>
```

However, my custom operation doesn't work:

```py
tf.user_ops.squared_out

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.user_ops' has no attribute 'squared_out'
```

Comment: There are a few problems with your question: Firstly, pick one language, not three. Further, extract a [mcve] and post that in your question. That said, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Edited based on your comments

Comment: Are there any updates to this problem? I would be really interested in finding a tutorial on how to use custom ops for windows! Or alternatively some insides about what to change in contrast to the linux tutorial presented [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/create_op)!

Thanks in advance!